# IntelliJ IDEA 14 : What is capture memory snapshot

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I tried to search this, but couldn't find, exactly what I am looking for

so someone please provide me an explanation on IDEA14's capture memory snapshot

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is added to 14 version for convenience reporting in case of memory troubles.

Snippet from [How to report IntelliJ IDEA performance problems](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192):

In case of memory related issues (***memory usage goes high, garbage is not collected***, etc) please use the *Memory snapshot button* in the menu near the CPU snapshot button. If it's not possible to get the snapshot because of the application crashing with ***OutOfMemory*** errors, please add the

> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

option to the IntelliJ IDEA JVM options. On the next ***OOM*** error the `.hrpof` dump will be produced and saved by the JVM (usually in the application working directory which is `IDEA_HOME\bin`).

Upload this dump to our FTP as described above in the CPU snapshot section.

***Please note that memory snapshot may contain the sensitive source code from your project.***

If you are uploading to a public service, use some password protection or enctyption. JetBrains FTP server is write only and you don't need to protect files uploaded there.

***Additional link***:

[Reporting performance problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems)

Comment: Thanks, the zipped .hrpof file is created in my HOME directory